# After login success how to disable fabric default screen from recent app

Tags: android, twitter-digits

I have integrated fabric digits in my android app,After successful login app will navigate to home screen ,But if i check recent apps from device hardware button ,It opens two apps one is home activity of my app and other one is enter your mobile number screen provided by digits,How to fix this.
here is my code for digits login

```
    @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
    Fabric.with(this, new TwitterCore(authConfig), new Digits());
   // Digits.authenticate(authCallback, R.style.AppBaseTheme);
    authCallback = new AuthCallback() {
        @Override
        public void success(DigitsSession session, String phoneNumber) {
            // Do something with the session
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            TwitterAuthToken authToken = (TwitterAuthToken) session.getAuthToken();
            DigitsOAuthSigning oauthSigning = new DigitsOAuthSigning(authConfig, authToken);
            Map<String, String> authHeaders = oauthSigning.getOAuthEchoHeadersForVerifyCredentials();
            ///call verification async
            retrieveValuesFromListMethod(authHeaders);
            PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
            try {
                // phone must begin with '+'
                Phonenumber.PhoneNumber numberProto = phoneUtil.parse(phoneNumber, "");
                countryCode = numberProto.getCountryCode();
                phone = numberProto.getNationalNumber();
            } catch (NumberParseException e) {
                System.err.println("NumberParseException was thrown: " + e.toString());
            }


            lookupPreference = getApplicationContext()
                    .getSharedPreferences("lookupPreference",
                            MODE_PRIVATE);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = lookupPreference.getString("user", "");
            user = gson.fromJson(json, User.class);
            user.setPhoneNumber(phone + "");
            user.setCountryCode(countryCode + "");
            user.setCountry("");
            json = gson.toJson(user);
            SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = lookupPreference.edit();
            prefsEditor.putString("user", json);
            prefsEditor.commit();


            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VerifyNumber.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("digitHeader", new JSONObject(authHeaders).toString());
            i.putExtra("values", b);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(i);

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(DigitsException exception) {
            // Do something on failure
        }
    };
    mInstance = this;
    // Register LocalyticsActivityLifecycleCallbacks
    registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new LocalyticsActivityLifecycleCallbacks(
            this));
}
```

Comment: Why you using i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); with intent ?

Comment: Because i'm starting activity from outside the activity so it is mandatory to use above line

Comment: @Sri, did you solve it ?

Comment: @Sri.. in version 1.10.3 I'm still facing this problem. did u manage to solve?

Comment: can you paste your manifest file?